# How to implement fast numpy array computation with multiple occuring slice indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-slicing

I was recently wondering how I could by-pass the following numpy behavior.
Starting with an simple example:

```
    import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 10]])
```

then:

```
b = a.copy()
b[:, [0,1,4,8]] = b[:, [0,1,4,8]] + 50
print(b)
```

...results in printing:

```
[[51 52  3  4 55  6  7  8 59  0]
 [61 62 13 14 65 16 17 18 69 10]]
```

but also taking one index double into the slice then:

```
c = a.copy()
c[:, [0,1,4,4,8]] = c[:, [0,1,4,4,8]] + 50
print(c)
```

giving:

```
[[51 52  3  4 55  6  7  8 59  0]
 [61 62 13 14 65 16 17 18 69 10]]
```

(in short; they do the same thing)

Could I also have that for index 4 it is executed 2 times? 
Or more practically; Let the slice element i be given r times: Can we let the above expression be applied r times, instead of numpy just taking it once into account? Also if we replace "50" by something that differs for every occurance of i?

For my current code, I used:

```
w[p1] = w[p1] + D[pix]
```

where I define "pix", "p1" as some numpy arrays with dtype int, same length and some integers may appear multiple times.

(So one may have pix = [..., 1,1,1,2,2,3,...] at the same time as p1 = [..., 21,32,13,23,11,78,...], however, thus resulting on its own into taking for index 1 only the first 1 and the corresponding 21 and scraping the rest of the ones.)

Of course using a for loop would solve the problem easily. The point is that both the integers and the sizes of the arrays are huge, so it would cost a lot of computational resources to use for-loops instead of efficient numpy-array routines. Any ideas, links to existing documentation etc.?

Comment: If you want to add different amounts to each element, just pass an array as the thing to add instead of a fixed number.

Comment: Also, simplify to `b[:, [0,1,4,8]] += 50`. As for your question, I am finding it hard to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: When you have duplicate indices, you need to use an `add.at` unbuffered operation.  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html